# Alternate ways to stop print() in python

Tags: python, command-line-interface, console-application, user-input

I have to get user input from the console. Using python input() statement only stops and returns the input when the user clicks "ENTER". But I want it to also happen with "TAB".

Is there a way that python input() can respond to both "ENTER" and "TAB" and return the user input?

I have tried different modules like msvcrt, keyboard, pynput, etc., But they simply read characters one by one. I had to deal with the below items:

- Shift + ch (for uppercase)
- Inserting characters in between (using right/left arrows)
- Copy and Paste
- Insert, etc

So I don't want to manually code for all these and many unknowns may raise in the future. These are all already taken care by python input(). I just need to stop it and return the output for "TAB" as well.

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this.
It might be helpful to a lot of users.

Comment: No. `input()` does what it does and there are no optional parameters to change it. As you have discovered, writing your own version is a surprising amount of work. That effort might be better spent learning a GUI framework such as `Tkinter` or `wxpython`.